# Aumentar tamanho da imagem

Tags: php

Bom, eu tenho este código que após prencher 1 formulário fazendo upload com uma imagem, esse código coloca a imagem que foi feita o upload numa pasta.

Código:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
$idcarro = $_POST["idcarro"];
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

        //INFO IMAGEM
        $file       = $_FILES['img'];
        $numFile    = count(array_filter($file['name']));

        //PASTA
        $folder     = 'imgcarros';

        //REQUISITOS
        $permite    = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
        $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;

        //MENSAGENS
        $msg        = array();
        $errorMsg   = array(
            1 => 'O arquivo no upload é maior do que o limite definido em upload_max_filesize no php.ini.',
            2 => 'O arquivo ultrapassa o limite de tamanho em MAX_FILE_SIZE que foi especificado no formulário HTML',
            3 => 'o upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente',
            4 => 'Não foi feito o upload do arquivo'
        );

        if($numFile <= 0){
            echo 'Selecione uma Imagem!';
        }else{
            for($i = 0; $i < $numFile; $i++){
                $name   = $file['name'][$i];
                $type   = $file['type'][$i];
                $size   = $file['size'][$i];
                $error  = $file['error'][$i];
                $tmp    = $file['tmp_name'][$i];

                $extensao = @end(explode('.', $name));
                $novoNome = rand().".$extensao";

                if($error != 0){
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> ".$errorMsg[$error];
                }else if(!in_array($type, $permite)){
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem não suportada!";
                }else if($size > $maxSize){
                    $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Erro imagem ultrapassa o limite de 5MB";
                }else{

                    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $folder.'/'.$novoNome)){
                        $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO imgcarros (idcarro, img) VALUES ('$idcarro', '$folder/$novoNome')");
                        $verifica = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM carros where id='$idcarro'");
                        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica);


?>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.alert("Foto enviada com Sucesso!");

</script>
<?php





                    }else{
                        $msg[] = "<b>$name :</b> Desculpe! Ocorreu um erro...";

                }

                foreach($msg as $pop){
                    echo $pop.'<br>';
            }
        }
    }
        }
    }
```

Porém eu quero fazer upload de uma foto com as dimensões: 2380x1422 pixeis, mas não consigo, porem se eu fizer upload de uma foto com os tamanhos 264*261 pixeis já consigo.

Como posso fazer para corrigir isso, para colocar tamanhos máximos de 4000x4000 pixeis?

Obrigado

Comment: No seu código não tem nada que limite a resolução da imagem, logo o problema de não conseguir enviar imagens com alta resolução não é em outro lugar. Talvez no tamanho do arquivo, verificou se tem 5Mb ou menos? Verifique o limite de upload do PHP no arquivo php.ini e no seu servidor web. Não sei quanto ao Apache, mas o Nginx tem um limite de upload também e você pode aumentar / diminuir no arquivo de conf.

Comment: `$maxSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5;` Experimentou aumentar isso? Aparentemente é o que tem no seu código limitando tamanho do arquivo. Agora, pra que permitir upload de 4000x4000? Tem certeza que é isso mesmo que você precisa?

Comment: Problema Resolvido!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código que apresentou não valida as dimensões (width, height).

Provavelmente o problema pode estar na validação do peso ou to mime type.

## Limite de peso para upload, no PHP

Nas configurações do PHP, defina o valor na diretiva `upload_max_filesize`.

Caso não saiba quanto está definido, apenas faça isso:

```
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize ');
```

Retornará o limite em bytes.

## Input hidden MAX_FILE_SIZE

Verifique também se no formulário HTML contém `MAX_FILE_SIZE`. Pois possui prioridade sobre o `upload_max_filesize` do PHP, caso seja menor. Note que browsers mais modernos ignoram esse parâmetro. Por precaução, para browsers mais antigos, é bom especificar. Por fim, a escolha depende do público alvo.

## Limite de tamanho no código

No código que postou há também um limite específico definido na variável `$maxSize`. O limite é de 5mb.

Aumente o limite caso seja necessário.

## Mime type e variações de tipos JPG.

Outro ponto que pode estar impedindo de fazer um upload é os tipos de arquivos permitidos, definidos na variável `$permite`

```
$permite = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
```

Os tipos JPG possuem variações. É recomendável adicionar também tais variações:

```
$permite = array(
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/jpg',
    'image/pjpg',
    'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png'
);
```

Comment: votei positivo, mas tem um detalhe aqui: "Note que browsers mais modernos ignoram esse parâmetro." na verdade esse parâmetro independe do browser. quem cuida do MAX_FILE_SIZE também é o PHP. A função desse parâmetro é cortar o envio mais rapidamente, sem ter que aceitar o upload até "estourar" o espaço. Para evitar do lado do cliente, você precisa de JS e da api de arquivos.

Comment: Obrigado, o problema não estava no tamanho da imagem mas sim no tamanho do arquivo.